# Expect the distributed table to return the results of each shard, not the aggregated value

Tags: clickhouse

There is a user tag table *table_tag*, the corresponding distributed table is *table_tag_all*, there are 6 shards in the cluster, sharding_key is *intHash64(user_id)*.

through setting the parameters *distributed_product_mode='local'* and *distributed_group_by_no_merge=1* so that the returned result is the value of 6 separate shards instead of an aggregated value.

The following are two tests.
Test 1 gets the correct result (6 records of count_1's number), but test 2 is aggregated(just 2 records).
How can I make test 2 return the results of 6 shards?

```sql
    create table database.table_tag on cluster c1
    (
    user_id  String,
    tag1     String,
    dt
    )
    order by user_id
    partition by dt
    setting index_granularity=128;
    
    /* test 1: */
    select
    sum(case when tag1='1' then 1 else 0 end ) as count_1
    from database.table_tag_all
    where dt in ('202102','202101')
    SETTINGS distributed_group_by_no_merge=1;
    
    
    /* test 2: */
    select count_1,count(1) 
    from (
    select
    user_id,
    sum(case when tag1='1' then 1 else 0 end ) as count_1
    from database.table_tag_all
    where dt in ('202102','202101')
    group by user_id
    SETTINGS distributed_group_by_no_merge=1;
    ) t1
    group by count_1
    SETTINGS distributed_group_by_no_merge=1;
    
    /*
    count_1  count()
    0        1222122
    1        33821
    */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT
    shard_number,
    count_1,
    count()
FROM
(
    SELECT
        any(_shard_num) AS shard_number,
        countIf(tag1 = '1') AS count_1
    FROM database.table_tag_all
    WHERE dt in ('202102','202101')
    GROUP BY user_id
)
GROUP BY
    shard_number,
    count_1
SETTINGS distributed_group_by_no_merge = 1
```